# How do I access an unhandled exception in an MVC Error view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, elmah

When the `HandleError` attribute on a controller detects an unhandled exception and redirects to the Error view, I would like to provide the user with a brief description of the error, and an option to email the error to the application administrator.

I do have a custom `HandleError` that notifies Elmah to log the error, but having to look up the error in the Elmah log seems a bit of a last resort.  Is there any other way to access the unhandled exception that is 'caught' by `HandleError`?

Comment: If you are logging the error, don't you have access to its description already?

Comment: Yes, but like I said, the controller that catches the error redirects to the Error view, so if I can avoid an error lookup in the DB it would be ideal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HandleErrorAttribute` supplies a Model object of type `HandleErrorInfo`
Your Error page could look like this

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<HandleErrorInfo>" %>
```

The Model has an `Exception` property with the details of the exception handled.

I usually use a custom error handler that also logs the exception using [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html) and I have an STMP appender that emails me whenever an exception is handled by the filter.