# Redirect to Error page in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I working in mvc 2 and need to redirect on error page with exception mesage.

For this I have i have override OnException () action  of controller
and trying to do like " View("Error").ExecuteResult(this.ControllerContext);"
but it is throwig exception 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper"

please give me the right solution

Regards Munish

Comment: could you show more code from that section?

Comment: protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
        {
           View("Error").ExecuteResult(this.ControllerContext);
        }

Comment: Hey munish, maybe this answer I gave may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397856/how-do-i-access-an-unhandled-exception-in-an-mvc-error-view/3398122#3398122

Answer (score 0):

The `HandleError` attribute redirects to the Error page that is placed in the shared folder. This page has a model of type `System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo` which contains an Exception property. You should modify the Error page so that it displays the exception information you want, like for example `<%:Model.Exception.Message %>`.

Also make sure that you have the `<customErrors mode="On" />` inside the `<system.web>` in the web.config file otherwise, during development the `HandleErrorAttribute` won´t intercept the exceptions.

Good luck!